# confirmation after submit a form

Tags: javascript, html

```
<script>

    var cor_credit = document.getElementById("cor_credit");
    var remain = document.getElementById("remain_credit");


    function validate() {
        if (remain.value < cor_credit.value) {
            return confirm('Do you really want to submit the form?');
        }
    }
</script>
```

In my HTMLform I have two input menus. One is "teachers remaining credit" and another is "course credit if remaining credit low from course credit." I want to add an alert on submit form, where the dialog will be: "Are you sure you want to submit with low credit?"

If remaining credits have enough from course it will be submit automatically.

Comment: `else return true` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add onsumbit attribute `<form name="myForm" onsubmit="return validate();">`

Then, change the script, to return true if `remain` more than `credit`

```
<script>

var cor_credit = document.getElementById("cor_credit");
var remain = document.getElementById("remain_credit");


function validate() {
    if (remain.value < cor_credit.value) {
        return confirm('Do you really want to submit the form?');
    }
    return true;
}
</script>
```

Comment: You don't really need `return true;`. If the function doesn't return `false`, the form will be submitted.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an `onsubmit` attribute in the form.

```
<form ... onsubmit="return validate();">
    ...
</form>
```